# Submit value to another page iframe form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

i want to submit a value to another page form from iframe look like this.

```
    <input form="form1" type="search><input form="form1" type="submit">

    <iframe src="anotherdomain">
    <form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1"></form>
    </iframe>
```

how to this? i want to submit a value without reload entire page instead only specific element in iframe.

Comment: That would potentially breach the security of the other website, so is not allowed *by the browser*. What is your overall aim?

Comment: my aims is submit a value without reload entire page so only specific element reload in iframe. there's anyway to get result like that?

Comment: Does it have to be from within your own website? You have not said what information you are submitting. Browser automation might be a better option depending on what you are trying to submit and why.

Comment: let's simple it. by default if we posted something it will reload entire page or direct to page on action atribute that we specific. and i want is seperated it in iframe so it will not reload entire page only in iframe. i think if we say its security problem i think it's wrong cause every website using validation both client side and server side so its imposibble to hack with iframe.

Comment: sory haha. i have already edit. what i want is cross page not domain submit a value in iframe form. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit data to "a form". That isn't what form submission does on the WWW. You can submit to *a URL* on a different site (which could be the same URL as their form uses). Just set the `action` attribute to an absolute URI. (This may be defeated if the target site implements protection against CSRF).

If you want to submit to an iframe, then use the `target` attribute on the form.

```
<form action="http://example.com/foo.php" method="post" target="name_of_iframe">
<!-- etc -->

<iframe src="http://example.com" name="name_of_iframe"></iframe>
```

---

If, on the other hand, you want to manipulate the DOM of the other website (e.g. to modify the value of an input displayed in the frame) through client side JavaScript then you'll need:

- The cooperation of the site you are trying to manipulate
- [`postMessage` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Comment: i try to put form in iframe and try to get value from foo.php. it's not work. is theres anyway to get result like this?

Comment: @jarwobangun — If you put a form inside the iframe (as opposed to on the page with a URL as the iframe's src), then it will be alternative content that is only used if iframes are not supported. Don't assume it will be there for browsers that do support iframes.

Comment: oh sory i think you get wrong what i want is cross page not domain in iframe form. is there anyway to this?